# Can not established Websocket secure connection on Firefox

Tags: javascript, python, firefox, websocket, tornado

I am stuck with Firefox. I could not make WebSocket work on it. I use Tornado Websocket and I initialized it by code below:

```
app = Application([(r'/mypath/ws', WSHandler)])
http_server = HTTPServer(app, ssl_options={
                "certfile": "~/certs/websocket.crt",
                "keyfile": "~/certs/websocket.key"
            })
http_server.listen("443")
```

And I initialized it on Javascript side like this:

```
var WS = new WebSocket("wss://websocket.localhost/mypath/ws");
```

This code works fine on Chrome, meanwhile, I created the cert by myself and run the page under HTTPS. But Firefox keeps saying that:

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at wss://websocket.localhost/mypath/ws.
```

I google it and found too many thoughts but none of'em worked for me :(

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you created the cert yourself... did you add it to your browser's trusted certificate list?

Comment: I should not add my own certificate manually to the browser because my clients won't do that. I have to find a permanent solution.

Comment: FatihKaratana Try what konghou said, if it works then you might have to buy a certificate from a trusted issuer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem via ProxyPass. I created a non-secure Websocket server with Tornado and run it on a specific port such as 3232:

```
app = Application([(r'/ws/', WSHandler)])
ws_server = HTTPServer(app)
ws_server.listen("3232")
```

Then I've written a proxypass in my Apache conf and use mod_proxy_wstunnel:

```
ProxyPass /ws/ ws://127.0.0.1:3232/ws/
ProxyPassReverse /ws/ ws://127.0.0.1:3232/ws/
```

And I create Websocket client on frontend like this:

```
var WS = new WebSocket("wss://websocket.localhost:81/ws/")
```

In this case I can create a connection on a secure connection with https and my port is 81 and my proxypass redirect any Websocket request to locally listened port 3232. It is not a exact solution mostly like a workaround. But it works fine for me.

Answer (score 25):

If it's a self-signed certificate, browsers won't show the dialog to accept the certificate if it's only used in a websocket.

You must first visit the requested url to see and accept the certificate warning, and then you can create the secure websocket.


For example if your websocket url is:

wss://localhost:44300/OpenWebSocket

then visit:

https://localhost:44300/OpenWebSocket

and accept the certificate warning

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it explains in detail how to resolve.

Comment: Although should have been proposed as an edit to the answer it quoted.

Answer (score 11):

If it's a self-signed certificate, browsers won't show the dialog to accept the certificate if it's only used in a websocket.  You must first visit a normal page on the same server to see and accept the certificate warning, and then you can create the secure websocket.

Comment: It still doesn't work even if I go to the host (localhost) before connecting. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1187666

Answer (score 1):

Try to open this url https://websocket.localhost/mypath/ws in firefox and accept certificate first.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me that I created my self-signed certificate in a wrong way, leaving the Basic Constraint -> Certificate Authority = Yes.

You can check that by visiting `about:preferences#privacy` in firefox, then click on the **View Certificates...** button. You will see the list of your websites/web apps and their certificates on the **Servers** tab. Click on your server and then click on the **View...** button.

A new window/tab will open with the details of the certificate. Scroll down to find the "Basic Constraints" section and there you will see if you generated that certificate declaring yourself as a Certificate Authority (CA). If so, you have to generate your certificate again without that constraint (CA=false)

Comment: After doing that, my web application run fine in HTTPS and my websocket server using WSS:// without needing any proxy or other tricks.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem adding a certificate exception in Firefox's advanced preferences.

Comment: You might be solve the issue by that way, but i've got no chance to force my users to do that :( That is the key-point for me. That is why i found a way workaround.

Answer (score -1):

I was pulling my hair out over this one for a while. I was getting all kinds of cryptic error messages depending on different web browsers, that all made it sound like it was something about certificate exceptions. I had already made exceptions in Firefox and Chrome,

**It turned out I had a typo in my sub-protocol string in my Javascript!**

Correcting the sub-protocol string made everything better.
More information on WebSockets and using sub-protocol(s): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket