# Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at wss://my_ip_address

Tags: firefox, websocket, wss

I have an issue with Firefox and WSS.

**This is my scenario:**

- a web app deployed on a Server A (internal ip: 192.168.x.y) in HTTPS on port 8843
- a socket deployed on Server B (internal ip: 192.168.j.k), in HTTPS on the same port 8843
- HTTPS are self-signed certificates.

Server A can establish connections with Server B.

When I go to the URL:
https://192.168.x.y/MyApp/index.html
there is a file "`.js`" that make a WSS connection with the URL:
wss://192.168.j.k/mySocket

On Google Chrome it works perfectly, the webapp connects on the WSS URL.
But when I try to open the page on Firefox, i see this error on the console:

"Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at wss://192.168.j.k/mySocket"

I tried to accept the certificates but it didn't work.
There is a solution for this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this solution? It may work for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775215/can-not-established-websocket-secure-connection-on-firefox