# Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at wss://server_ip:port

Tags: php, websocket, symfony-2.8

Am using 
[Gos Web Socket Bundle](https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle) and the application hosted on Apache server.

application config.yml

```
gos_web_socket:
server:
    port: 8000
    host: [SERVER IP]
pushers:
    wamp:
        port: 8000
        host: [SERVER IP]
```

Then Starting the websocketserver

```
php app/console gos:websocket:server
```

and on client side 'twig'

```
 {{ ws_client() }}
    <script>
       var wsConnectUrl = "wss://{{gos_websocket_ip}}:{{gos_webscoket_port}}";
    </script>
```

when open the page with http the socket connected well. But when connect via https
i got that errror

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at wss://SERVER_IP:8000/
```

i found many solution on stackoverflow but nothing fix my issue 
this is the most referrals one [Can not established Websocket secure connection on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775215/can-not-established-websocket-secure-connection-on-firefox)

Any help on that even with some clarification on above solution for my case here?

file /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf

```
 # Certificate
 cert = /my/way/to/ssl.crt
 key = /my/way/to/not_crypted.key


 socket = l:TCP_NODELAY=1
 socket = r:TCP_NODELAY=1

 chroot = /var/run/stunnel4/
 pid = /stunnel.pid

 [websockets]
 accept = 8000
 connect = 8000
```

Comment: did you configure ssl? https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle/blob/master/Resources/docs/Ssl.md

Comment: Yes i configured it

Comment: i just attached the ssl config file