# Getting error on FireFox while using websocket php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, firefox, websocket, ratchet

I want to show realtime data on browser. I am using Rachet library for websocket. It is working on localhost in all browsers. After uploading on the linux shared hosting, it works fine on all  browser except only mozilla Firefox. On the mozilla it gives error.

index.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>WebSocket Chat</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>WebSocket Chat</h1>
  <div id="chatBox"></div>
  <input type="text" id="messageInput" placeholder="Type your message..." />
  <button id="sendButton">Send</button>

  <script>
    const socket = new WebSocket('wss://mydomain.com/websocket1:8081');

    // Function to save message on the server
        function saveMessage(message) {
          const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open('POST', 'save-message.php');
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ message: message }));
        }

    // Function to fetch messages from the server
    function fetchMessages() {
     const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', 'fetch-messages.php');
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
              if (xhr.status === 200) {
                const messages = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                const chatBox = document.getElementById('chatBox');
                messages.forEach(function(message) {
              const messageElement = document.createElement('div');
              messageElement.textContent = message.fname;
              chatBox.appendChild(messageElement);
            });
          } else {
            console.log('Error fetching messages:', xhr.status);
          }
        }
      };
      xhr.send();
    }

    // Event listener for receiving messages from the server
    socket.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
      const message = event.data;
      const chatBox = document.getElementById('chatBox');
      const messageElement = document.createElement('div');
      messageElement.textContent = message;
      chatBox.appendChild(messageElement);
    });

    const sendButton = document.getElementById('sendButton');
    sendButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      const messageInput = document.getElementById('messageInput');
      const message = messageInput.value;
      socket.send(message);
      messageInput.value = '';

      // Save the sent message on the server
      saveMessage(message);
    });

    // Fetch messages when the page loads
    fetchMessages();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My server.php is:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
  protected $clients;

  public function __construct() {
   $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
  }

public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
$request = $conn->httpRequest;

// Handle the WebSocket handshake here
// You can perform any necessary checks or validation before accepting the connection

// Example: Check if the WebSocket upgrade header is present
if (!$request->hasHeader('Upgrade') || strtolower($request->getHeader('Upgrade')[0]) !== 'websocket') {
    // Close the connection if the Upgrade header is missing or incorrect
    $conn->close();
    return;
}

// Example: Check if the request contains the expected WebSocket version
if (!$request->hasHeader('Sec-WebSocket-Version') || $request->getHeader('Sec-WebSocket-Version')[0] !== '13') {
    // Close the connection if the WebSocket version is not supported
    $conn->close();
    return;
}

// Example: Check other necessary conditions

// Store the connection
$this->clients->attach($conn);
}


  public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
    $message = htmlspecialchars($msg);

    foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
      $client->send($message);
    }
  }

  public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    $this->clients->detach($conn);
  }

  public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
    echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
    $conn->close();
  }
}

$chat = new Chat;
$server = IoServer::factory(
  new HttpServer(
    new WsServer($chat)
  ),
  8081
);

$server->run();
```

The websocket is working all the browser except only firefox. It gives error:
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://cstechnologyindia.com/websocket1.

I am trying to solve it from past 2 days.
I'm using a shared hosting. The hosting provider is saying that everything is perfect from our side. Now I'm hopeless. Please solve my problem anyone.  Please check added image.
Also I've valid https certificate. Please check attached image.
[image]

[image]

In the server **Apache web socket module** is installed and the port is opened.

Comment: A certificate issue perhaps, similar to what's described in https://stackoverflow.com/q/23775215/1427878 ?

Comment: I assume the part you cut off ... a) identifies the correct host/ip:port; AND b) there's no other information in that error that could be useful

Comment: The  error is:

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://cstechnologyindia.com/websocket1:8081.

Comment: Please help for this. I've been stucked in this  from yeterday.

Comment: I've  trused certificate.